# Websockets ExecutorSubscribableChannel class keeps on sending heartbeat every 15 sec

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, rabbitmq-stomp

I'm using spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE with websocket support and RabbitMQ as external broker with stomp support.

The issue is that the client keeps on getting a heartbeat message **"\n"** every  +-15 secs even though the client negotiated the heatbeat as **"0, 30000"** during the CONNECT request as suggested in this [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#stomp) on heart-beat header support with stomp in RabbitMQ. By turning on trace log I was able to find that **ExecutorSubscribableChannel** has a `run()` method that gets executed by a **ThreadPoolExecutor** every +-15 secs, which in turn sends that heartbeat message. I'm not sure if its a bug or I'm missing some configuration on my side. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to solve this with help on feedback provided on the issue that i opened in spring-framework GitHub. Here is the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25781).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with help on feedback provided on the issue that I opened in spring-framework GitHub. Here is the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25781).